# Print filename, number of line with file size and modification date

Tags: awk, ls, wc

I want to print the File Name, Size of file, modification date, Number of line in a file.

At present I use below command to achieve my work but it's hectic to do manually everytime

```
ls -lrth file1.csv file2.csv
```

I copy filename, size of file and modification date

Than I execute

```
wc -l file1.csv file2.csv
```

And I copy number of line

Basically my final result look like something as below

```
74537 4780K Mar 10 14:57 file1.csv
7462 47K Mar 10 13:05 file2.csv
```

Comment: Use [code blocks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to format your post. Provide the same order in both your description and the desired output for the sake of the principle of least surprise.

Comment: if you have [GNU find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) available in your *nix box, take a look in `man find` and `-printf format` section

Comment: Lazy, unoptimized first throw: join -1 9 -2 2 <(ls -lrth *.csv |sort -k 9) <(wc -l *.csv |sort -k2)|awk '{print $10" "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9" "$1}' | column -t

Comment: Better: `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next}{print a[$9]" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9}' <(wc -l *.htm) <(ls -lrth *.htm)`. No time to write an explanation though, sorry

Comment: @AlexStragies see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU tools and bash:

```
$ while IFS=$'\t' read -r -d $'\0' stats name; do
    printf '%s %s %s\n' "$(wc -l < "$name")" "$stats" "$name"
done < <(find . -type f -name '*.txt' -printf '%s %Tb %Td %TH:%TM\t%p\0')
3 36 Mar 10 11:06 ./bar.txt
100 292 Mar 10 19:12 ./foo.txt
```